# Objective-C Assigning to UIView from incompatible type block

Tags: objective-c, types, block

I was trying to assign an `UIView` to an `UITableView` footer with a block.

This works fine:

```
UIView* (^createFooter)() = ^UIView*{
            UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100)];
            return footer;
            };
myTableView.tableFooterView = createFooter();
```

Why isn't this working:

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = ^UIView*{
            UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100)];
            return footer;
            };
```

Thanks for telling me what I missed about using block!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you've provided, you declare your block on the first line and then call it on the second. Calling the block is implied by `()`, which you have on the second line.

In your second example, you're assigning the view to be the block rather than the results of calling that block. You need to add a `()` to the end in order to actually invoke the block you've declared inline. So, instead of

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = ^UIView *{ ... };
```

You need

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = ^UIView *{ ... }();
```

Answer (score 0):

the above code is to define a block and invoke the block to return a view.
the below code is to assign a block to a view, so error!

You can invoke a block more than twice like this:

```
myTableView.tableFooterView = createFooter();
myTableView.tableHeaderView = createFooter();
```

createFooter() is a block defined by

```
^UIView*{
            UIView *footer = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,300,100)];
            return footer;
            };
```

this is not a `UIView` value.